# Pasar objeto como parametro y comparar sus atributos

Tags: javascript

Hola buenas noches.
Quiero realizar un método llamado "jugar" donde se recibe un objeto por parámetro, el método consta de comparar los atributos de este objeto (ejemplo, fuerza, resistencia y poderes, todo en numeros int) y el que tenga mayor valor en al menos 2 de 3 atributos gana. Mi consulta es como podria comparar los atributos.

`public jugar(Superheroe superheroe){}`

Comment: si pasas el un objeto con un "." puedes acceder a los atributos
public jugar(superheroe1, superheroe2){
        if (Superheroe1.fuera > Superheroe2.fuerza){
        }
}

objeto.jugar(superheroe1, superheroe2);

es a lo que te referias?

Comment: Hola gracias por responder! sii eso mismo buscaba comparar atributos de diferentes objetos, no sabia que era con el "." gracias !!